# Can Civiccrm do this?

Tags: wordpress

I am volunteering for a non profit organization to implement the following functionalities in their WordPress website:

1.New members would have a registration form (with full range of personal, education, career and business fields including photo) for entering their complete profile

2.New members who have a front-end dashboard.

3.Members would have the ability to edit their profile through the front end dashboard

4.Members registration details would be fed into their profile and included in a general membership directory view-able to website visitors
I have never used civiccrm and since I have not found a full list of its features I wonder if it is capable to add them.

Thank you.

Comment: https://civicrm.org/civicrm-101

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to CiviCRM

CiviCRM can do all the above listed features and more

But first you need know more about wordpress and CiviCRM - you can do this by palying around in Civicrm wordpress demo site which will give you more idea regarding your need

Demo Link: https://civicrm.org/sandboxes - 
http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-login.php

refer: https://civicrm.org/will-civicrm-meet-your-needs

All the best for your CiviCRM Learning

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Thank you for your interest :) I am going to evaluate Buddypress to to see what is the more intuitive and compatible with the requirements.